# History timeline, controlling left space and width generated from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a history timeline with `CSS` and `jQuery` and its working fine, but the issue I am facing with the width of `li` and their spacing from left, its not equal, I am trying to show each `li` with equal width and spacing from left and right equal and other thing, show the four `li` in first slide and show the last `li` in next slide, can anyone please help?

Here is the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/gs7vphy7/2/) demo

**CSS**

```
<style>
      /* -------------------------------- 
  History timeline
  -------------------------------- */
  .cd-horizontal-timeline {
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 2em auto;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline::before {
    /* never visible - this is used in jQuery to check the current MQ */
    content: 'mobile';
    display: none;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline.loaded {
    /* show the timeline after events position has been set (using JavaScript) */
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .timeline {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    /*max-width: 800px;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-wrapper::after, .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-wrapper::before {
    /* these are used to create a shadow effect at the sides of the timeline */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-wrapper::before {
    left: 0;
    /*background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( left , #f8f8f8, rgba(248, 248, 248, 0));
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f8f8f8, rgba(248, 248, 248, 0));*/
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-wrapper::after {
    right: 0;
    /*background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( right , #f8f8f8, rgba(248, 248, 248, 0));
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #f8f8f8, rgba(248, 248, 248, 0));*/
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events {
    /* this is the grey line/timeline */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 49px;
    height: 2px;
    /* width will be set using JavaScript */
    background: #d1d2d3;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .filling-line {
    /* this is used to create the green line filling the timeline */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00355f;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    -o-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -ms-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    color: #383838;
    /* fix bug on Safari - text flickering while timeline translates */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events a::after {
    /* this is used to create the event spot */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: -6px;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
  }
  .no-touch .cd-horizontal-timeline .events a:hover::after {
    background-color: #00355f;
    border-color: #00355f;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events a.selected {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events a.selected::after {
    background-color: #00355f;
    border-color: #00355f;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events a.older-event::after {
    border-color: #00355f;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
    .cd-horizontal-timeline {
      margin: 6em auto;
    }
    .cd-horizontal-timeline::before {
      /* never visible - this is used in jQuery to check the current MQ */
      content: 'desktop';
    }
  }

  .cd-timeline-navigation a {
    /* these are the left/right arrows to navigate the timeline */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #d1d2d3;
    /* replace text with an icon */
    overflow: hidden;
    color: transparent;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s;
    transition: border-color 0.3s;
  }
  .cd-timeline-navigation a::after {
    /* arrow icon */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 90%;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: auto;
    right: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(../images/cd-arrow.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
  }
  .cd-timeline-navigation a.prev {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
  }
  .cd-timeline-navigation a.next {
    right: 0;
  }
  .no-touch .cd-timeline-navigation a:hover {
    border-color: #00355f;
  }
  .cd-timeline-navigation a.inactive {
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }
  .cd-timeline-navigation a.inactive::after {
    background-position: 0 -25px;
  }
  .no-touch .cd-timeline-navigation a.inactive:hover {
    border-color: #dfdfdf;
  }

  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2em 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.4s;
    transition: height 0.4s;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content li {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    padding: 0 5%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content li.selected {
    /* visible event content */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content li.enter-right, .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content li.leave-right {
    -webkit-animation-name: cd-enter-right;
    -moz-animation-name: cd-enter-right;
    animation-name: cd-enter-right;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content li.enter-left, .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content li.leave-left {
    -webkit-animation-name: cd-enter-left;
    -moz-animation-name: cd-enter-left;
    animation-name: cd-enter-left;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content li.leave-right, .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content li.leave-left {
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content li > * {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.6rem;
    font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content em {
    display: block;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content em::before {
    content: '- ';
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content p {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #959595;
  }
  .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content em, .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content p {
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content h2 {
      font-size: 7rem;
    }
    .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content em {
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
    .cd-horizontal-timeline .events-content p {
      font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes cd-enter-right {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes cd-enter-right {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
  }
  @keyframes cd-enter-right {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
      -o-transform: translateX(100%);
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
      -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
      -o-transform: translateX(0%);
      transform: translateX(0%);
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes cd-enter-left {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes cd-enter-left {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
  }
  @keyframes cd-enter-left {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
      -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
      -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
      -o-transform: translateX(0%);
      transform: translateX(0%);
    }
  }
<style>
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="cd-horizontal-timeline">
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="events-wrapper">
      <div class="events">
        <ol>
          <li><a href="#0" data-date="01/01/2001" class="selected">2001</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0" data-date="01/01/2003">2003</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0" data-date="01/01/2007">2007</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0" data-date="01/01/2013">2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0" data-date="01/01/2014">2014</a></li>
        </ol>
        <span class="filling-line" aria-hidden="true"></span> </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="cd-timeline-navigation">
      <li><a href="#0" class="prev inactive">Prev</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0" class="next">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="events-content">
    <ol>
      <li class="selected" data-date="01/01/2001"> <em>2001</em>
        <p>Content Here</p>
      </li>
      <li data-date="01/01/2003"> <em>2003</em>
        <p>Content</p>
      </li>
      <li data-date="01/01/2007"> <em>2007</em>
        <p>Content</p>
      </li>
      <li data-date="01/01/2013"> <em>2013</em>
        <p>Content</p>
      </li>
      <li data-date="01/01/2014"> <em>2014</em>
        <p>Content</p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</section>
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var timelines = $('.cd-horizontal-timeline'),
    eventsMinDistance = 60;

(timelines.length > 0) && initTimeline(timelines);

function initTimeline(timelines) {
    timelines.each(function() {
        var timeline = $(this),
            timelineComponents = {};
        //cache timeline components 
        timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'] = timeline.find('.events-wrapper');
        timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'] = timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].children('.events');
        timelineComponents['fillingLine'] = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].children('.filling-line');
        timelineComponents['timelineEvents'] = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('a');
        timelineComponents['timelineDates'] = parseDate(timelineComponents['timelineEvents']);
        timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse'] = minLapse(timelineComponents['timelineDates']);
        timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'] = timeline.find('.cd-timeline-navigation');
        timelineComponents['eventsContent'] = timeline.children('.events-content');

        //assign a left postion to the single events along the timeline
        setDatePosition(timelineComponents, eventsMinDistance);
        //assign a width to the timeline
        var timelineTotWidth = setTimelineWidth(timelineComponents, eventsMinDistance);
        //the timeline has been initialize - show it
        timeline.addClass('loaded');

        //detect click on the next arrow
        timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].on('click', '.next', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            updateSlide(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'next');
        });
        //detect click on the prev arrow
        timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].on('click', '.prev', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            updateSlide(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'prev');
        });
        //detect click on the a single event - show new event content
        timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].on('click', 'a', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            updateOlderEvents($(this));
            updateFilling($(this), timelineComponents['fillingLine'], timelineTotWidth);
            updateVisibleContent($(this), timelineComponents['eventsContent']);
        });

        //on swipe, show next/prev event content
        timelineComponents['eventsContent'].on('swipeleft', function() {
            var mq = checkMQ();
            (mq == 'mobile') && showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'next');
        });
        timelineComponents['eventsContent'].on('swiperight', function() {
            var mq = checkMQ();
            (mq == 'mobile') && showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'prev');
        });

        //keyboard navigation
        $(document).keyup(function(event) {
            if (event.which == '37' && elementInViewport(timeline.get(0))) {
                showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'prev');
            } else if (event.which == '39' && elementInViewport(timeline.get(0))) {
                showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'next');
            }
        });
    });
}

function updateSlide(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, string) {
    //retrieve translateX value of timelineComponents['eventsWrapper']
    var translateValue = getTranslateValue(timelineComponents['eventsWrapper']),
        wrapperWidth = Number(timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].css('width').replace('px', ''));
    //translate the timeline to the left('next')/right('prev') 
    (string == 'next') ?
    translateTimeline(timelineComponents, translateValue - wrapperWidth + eventsMinDistance, wrapperWidth - timelineTotWidth): translateTimeline(timelineComponents, translateValue + wrapperWidth - eventsMinDistance);
}

function showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, string) {
    //go from one event to the next/previous one
    var visibleContent = timelineComponents['eventsContent'].find('.selected'),
        newContent = (string == 'next') ? visibleContent.next() : visibleContent.prev();

    if (newContent.length > 0) { //if there's a next/prev event - show it
        var selectedDate = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('.selected'),
            newEvent = (string == 'next') ? selectedDate.parent('li').next('li').children('a') : selectedDate.parent('li').prev('li').children('a');

        updateFilling(newEvent, timelineComponents['fillingLine'], timelineTotWidth);
        updateVisibleContent(newEvent, timelineComponents['eventsContent']);
        newEvent.addClass('selected');
        selectedDate.removeClass('selected');
        updateOlderEvents(newEvent);
        updateTimelinePosition(string, newEvent, timelineComponents);
    }
}

function updateTimelinePosition(string, event, timelineComponents) {
    //translate timeline to the left/right according to the position of the selected event
    var eventStyle = window.getComputedStyle(event.get(0), null),
        eventLeft = Number(eventStyle.getPropertyValue("left").replace('px', '')),
        timelineWidth = Number(timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].css('width').replace('px', '')),
        timelineTotWidth = Number(timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].css('width').replace('px', ''));
    var timelineTranslate = getTranslateValue(timelineComponents['eventsWrapper']);

    if ((string == 'next' && eventLeft > timelineWidth - timelineTranslate) || (string == 'prev' && eventLeft < -timelineTranslate)) {
        translateTimeline(timelineComponents, -eventLeft + timelineWidth / 2, timelineWidth - timelineTotWidth);
    }
}

function translateTimeline(timelineComponents, value, totWidth) {
    var eventsWrapper = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].get(0);
    value = (value > 0) ? 0 : value; //only negative translate value
    value = (!(typeof totWidth === 'undefined') && value < totWidth) ? totWidth : value; //do not translate more than timeline width
    setTransformValue(eventsWrapper, 'translateX', value + 'px');
    //update navigation arrows visibility
    (value == 0) ? timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].find('.prev').addClass('inactive'): timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].find('.prev').removeClass('inactive');
    (value == totWidth) ? timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].find('.next').addClass('inactive'): timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].find('.next').removeClass('inactive');
}

function updateFilling(selectedEvent, filling, totWidth) {
    //change .filling-line length according to the selected event
    var eventStyle = window.getComputedStyle(selectedEvent.get(0), null),
        eventLeft = eventStyle.getPropertyValue("left"),
        eventWidth = eventStyle.getPropertyValue("width");
    eventLeft = Number(eventLeft.replace('px', '')) + Number(eventWidth.replace('px', '')) / 2;
    var scaleValue = eventLeft / totWidth;
    setTransformValue(filling.get(0), 'scaleX', scaleValue);
}

function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min) {
    for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i++) {
        var distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]),
            distanceNorm = Math.round(distance / timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
        timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', distanceNorm * min + 'px');
    }
}

function setTimelineWidth(timelineComponents, width) {
    var timeSpan = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length - 1]),
        timeSpanNorm = timeSpan / timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse'],
        timeSpanNorm = Math.round(timeSpanNorm) + 4,
        totalWidth = timeSpanNorm * width;
    timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].css('width', totalWidth + 'px');
    updateFilling(timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('a.selected'), timelineComponents['fillingLine'], totalWidth);
    updateTimelinePosition('next', timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('a.selected'), timelineComponents);

    return totalWidth;
}

function updateVisibleContent(event, eventsContent) {
    var eventDate = event.data('date'),
        visibleContent = eventsContent.find('.selected'),
        selectedContent = eventsContent.find('[data-date="' + eventDate + '"]'),
        selectedContentHeight = selectedContent.height();

    if (selectedContent.index() > visibleContent.index()) {
        var classEnetering = 'selected enter-right',
            classLeaving = 'leave-left';
    } else {
        var classEnetering = 'selected enter-left',
            classLeaving = 'leave-right';
    }

    selectedContent.attr('class', classEnetering);
    visibleContent.attr('class', classLeaving).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function() {
        visibleContent.removeClass('leave-right leave-left');
        selectedContent.removeClass('enter-left enter-right');
    });
    eventsContent.css('height', selectedContentHeight + 'px');
}

function updateOlderEvents(event) {
    event.parent('li').prevAll('li').children('a').addClass('older-event').end().end().nextAll('li').children('a').removeClass('older-event');
}

function getTranslateValue(timeline) {
    var timelineStyle = window.getComputedStyle(timeline.get(0), null),
        timelineTranslate = timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
        timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
        timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
        timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
        timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("transform");

    if (timelineTranslate.indexOf('(') >= 0) {
        var timelineTranslate = timelineTranslate.split('(')[1];
        timelineTranslate = timelineTranslate.split(')')[0];
        timelineTranslate = timelineTranslate.split(',');
        var translateValue = timelineTranslate[4];
    } else {
        var translateValue = 0;
    }

    return Number(translateValue);
}

function setTransformValue(element, property, value) {
    element.style["-webkit-transform"] = property + "(" + value + ")";
    element.style["-moz-transform"] = property + "(" + value + ")";
    element.style["-ms-transform"] = property + "(" + value + ")";
    element.style["-o-transform"] = property + "(" + value + ")";
    element.style["transform"] = property + "(" + value + ")";
}

//based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript
function parseDate(events) {
    var dateArrays = [];
    events.each(function() {
        var singleDate = $(this),
            dateComp = singleDate.data('date').split('T');
        if (dateComp.length > 1) { //both DD/MM/YEAR and time are provided
            var dayComp = dateComp[0].split('/'),
                timeComp = dateComp[1].split(':');
        } else if (dateComp[0].indexOf(':') >= 0) { //only time is provide
            var dayComp = ["2000", "0", "0"],
                timeComp = dateComp[0].split(':');
        } else { //only DD/MM/YEAR
            var dayComp = dateComp[0].split('/'),
                timeComp = ["0", "0"];
        }
        var newDate = new Date(dayComp[2], dayComp[1] - 1, dayComp[0], timeComp[0], timeComp[1]);
        dateArrays.push(newDate);
    });
    return dateArrays;
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
    return Math.round((second - first));
}

function minLapse(dates) {
    //determine the minimum distance among events
    var dateDistances = [];
    for (i = 1; i < dates.length; i++) {
        var distance = daydiff(dates[i - 1], dates[i]);
        dateDistances.push(distance);
    }
    return Math.min.apply(null, dateDistances);
}

/*
    How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport
*/
function elementInViewport(el) {
    var top = el.offsetTop;
    var left = el.offsetLeft;
    var width = el.offsetWidth;
    var height = el.offsetHeight;

    while (el.offsetParent) {
        el = el.offsetParent;
        top += el.offsetTop;
        left += el.offsetLeft;
    }

    return (
        top < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
        left < (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth) &&
        (top + height) > window.pageYOffset &&
        (left + width) > window.pageXOffset
    );
}

function checkMQ() {
    //check if mobile or desktop device
    return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.cd-horizontal-timeline'), '::before').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/'/g, "").replace(/"/g, "");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to customizing 'Horizontal Timeline' but I have two options

1. modify javascript code. `setDatePosition` determine the position after parsing 'date' 
   so modify it.

   ```
   function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min) {
     for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i++) { 
         var distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]),
           distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
         timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', distanceNorm*min+'px');
     }
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min) {
     for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i++) { 
         timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', i*min+'px');
     }
   }
   ```

   where `min` is `eventsMinDistance = 60` you have to calculate distance (width / 4).
2. If you don't like modify function. well, we can cheat her. :) 
   don't give the real date but sequential date.

   ```
   data-date="01/01/2001" class="..."
   data-date="01/01/2003"
   data-date="01/01/2007"
   ```

   to

   ```
   data-date="01/01/2001" class="..."
   data-date="01/01/2002"
   data-date="01/01/2003"
   ```

   this way also needs right `eventsMinDistance`

btw, `ul ol { list-style: none; }` is missing in your css file.

Comment: thanks @Yourim Yi both of the options were helpful, however I did modified the function and got it working perfectly, thanks a lot!